# Confirming the Updated User Email address in Django with a Boolean

Tags: django, authentication, django-models, django-views, boolean

Am creating **profile Update**. It works fine and l can change the *Username* and the *Email*. But l would like to **confirm** the New submitted email by sending an *otp* or a *verification link* , so that a user can verify that email.

I have been looking for the solution of doing it but l just found one post on *Stackoverflow*, whereby someone is suggesting that *you can deactivate the user and send a confirmation email and then activate him or her again*

But am asking;
**ls it possible to create a model with a Boolean field and connect that model to a User model, so that l can set that Boolean field to send a verification code to User who changed his or her email Address?**

**email_comfirm.py**

```
#email comfirm model 

class EmailComfirm(models.Model):
user=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
is_comfirmed=models.BooleanField(default=True)
active_otp=models.CharField(max_lenght=8)
```

If possible;
**How can l phrase that model and it's function?**

I would like to call that Boolean to check if the email is changed, and if changed, turns off or set *false and process the verification link* after confirming the email it sets *true.*

`is_comfirmed() = False`

Secondly;
**How am l going to confirm that email?**

To me l would like to *generate the otp after, l save it in the model* and pass it in the email am sending to the user. Then l it use that otp sent to the user via email to *check if the otp matches with the one in database and turn to True to save the user email*

And;
**How can I generate the otp for the new email and and save it in the database?**

I suggest to use JavaScript if possible to generate the otp or an way possible and save it in the database after to be used for verification.

If my suggestion can work;
**Any to help me with a live example of how l can phase it let it be working because l have it in mind but l don't know how to how make it**

*And its not perfect correct because it's an idea l have. I accept to be corrected in anyway to let it happen*